# VS Code creating text file in wrong directory (possible path issue)

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, directory

I'm creating a program in C++ on VS Code macOS. I have this line of code:

```
fileO.open("writing.txt", ios::app);
```

which is supposed to open a new `.txt` file and save whatever the user inputs into my program. However, VS Code is opening the file under the directory `/Users/username` instead of the directory where my program is located, which is `/Users/username/Downloads/firstprogram/code.cpp`. This seems to be a very simple problem but I cannot seem to find a correct answer for this. I only get results for non-relevent threads about directories in VS Code.

It is still able to access the same `writing.txt` file when I re-run my program and the `.txt` file still keeps the previous data. My program works 100% correctly because I coded it in a school-based linux `ssh` shell/editor and it was perfectly fine. This is a VS Code issue.

I have been unable to fix it despite following the VS Code macOS setup for C++. My `launch.json` files and `tasks.json` files have also been updated to match the files on the official VS Code website but I am still encountering issues related to the path of files being created. This is very confusing because I've never had this happen to python files that I create using programs, but it's occurring for my C++ programs. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: How do you run your program? Have you configured the `launch.json` file to set the correct [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I configure the `launch.json` through vs code?

Comment: Considering the `/Users` directory I assume you're on a macOS system? If so please read e.g. [this VSCode on Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) guide.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read through the article and all of my `.vscode` files look identical to the ones in the article. Still having the same issue. Any suggestions?